# react native activity crashes, probably related to packaging okhttp3

Tags: react-native, okhttp

have been struggling with this for a week, with no success.

I have started from a good boiler plate app (just another app), and added a click with detail activity being a React native activity.

As soon as I make the click the whole app crashes.

> 03-25 14:58:35.731 2746-4224/com.justanotherandroidapp.develop
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>                                                                                    Process: com.justanotherandroidapp.develop, PID: 2746
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
>                                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                     **Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   setCallWebSocket(Lokhttp3/Call;)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/Internal;**
>   or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Internal'
>   appears in
>   /data/app/com.justanotherandroidapp.develop-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes57.dex)
>                                                                                        **at okhttp3.ws.WebSocketCall.enqueue(WebSocketCall.java:108)**
>                                                                                        at
>   com.facebook.react.devsupport.InspectorPackagerConnection$Connection.connect(InspectorPackagerConnection.java:243)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.facebook.react.devsupport.InspectorPackagerConnection.connect(InspectorPackagerConnection.java:44)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper$3.doInBackground(DevServerHelper.java:168)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper$3.doInBackground(DevServerHelper.java:164)
>                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>
> ```
>                                                                              --------- beginning of system
> ```

The whole app is on GitHub 
https://github.com/vladp/Just-Another-Android-App

It crashes in ReactNative's   DevSuportManagerImpl.java (using react native 0.42, API 25)
between these 2 calls

```
  mDevServerHelper.openPackagerConnection(this);
  mDevServerHelper.openInspectorConnection();
```

(line 878, 879 in node_modules\react-native\android\com\facebook\react\react-native\0.42.3\react-native-0.42.3-sources.jar!\com\facebook\react\devsupport\DevSupportManagerImpl.java  )

The issue does not improve whether I delete or add okhttp  and okhttp-ws
from my [build.gradle](https://github.com/vladp/Just-Another-Android-App/blob/develop/app/build.gradle)

```
//React Native  -- start
compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.42.+"){
            // https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10233
            exclude group:'com.facebook.stetho', module:'stetho'
            exclude module: 'jsr305'

}

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.2'
```

Appreciate in advance any help.

Answer (score 9):

finally figured out what to do.
I forced gradle to resolve all references to okhttp to version 3.4.1.
Thankfully in my test app, all the other components tolerated being 'forced to lowest common denominator' (that being the 3.4.1 version of okhttp used by react native).

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        // force certain versions of dependencies (including transitive)
        force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    }
}
```

The above line turned out to be solution for which I spent probably 30 hours on...

Comment: Thanks. I find myself in the similar situation, whilst I have 4 different libs in different modules that each of these libs include a different version of okhttp3. In order to resolve the `NoSuchMethodError` issue, I have to force all these libs to use the same okhttp3 version as the one comes with Retrofit. The method you posted resolved my issue. Also, this gradle command helped a lot `./gradlew :moduleName:dependencies` to locate which lib in which module has the dependencies.